# using ESM imports in functions

Tags: node.js

when you add `imports` to an ESM package, you can resolve alias paths into the corresponding real ones, like this:

package.json

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "imports": { "#*": "./*" }
  ...
}
```

now we can use it like this `import something from "#module"` which resolves into `import something from "./module"`

but, I can't see any docs about using the same resolving mechanism for builtin functions (or maybe user functions either) that accept PathLike arguments like `readFileSync`

```
readFileSync("#file.txt")
```

I know it is a **module** resolving, but we can use it as a path resolving.

my question is: how to achieve the same mechanism to resolve any PathLike path, without a manual modification, because simply we need to dispense the relative paths

an example of manual resolving

```
function example(path: PathLike){
  let imports = /* read the property imports from package.json */
  let keys = Object.keys(imports)

  // make a loop, and for each key make something like this (needs additional work)
  let resolvedPath = path.replace('#','./')

  // now, use resolvedPath instead of path
}
```

example of nodejs resolving

```
function example2(path: PathLike){
  let resolvedPath = resolve(path)
}
```

in addition to the original work of resolve() it also uses the property `import` to resolve the path to avoid using relative paths

I ask if there is a way to achieve this goal.

**The solution**

thanks to @RickN this is the final solution:

```
export function resolveImports(path: PathLike): Promise<string> {
  return import.meta!.resolve!(path.toString()).then((resolvedPath) =>
    fileURLToPath(resolvedPath)
  );
}
```

Comment: You can't use it for all paths or strings, only for module resolution.

Comment: I added additional information to explain more about what exactly I need

Comment: I understand what you want, but Node.js doesn't provide such functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of writing, you need a CLI flag to enable the [resolve](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/esm.html#importmetaresolvespecifier-parent) method in `import.meta`:

```
node --experimental-import-meta-resolve your-file.js
```

(The first part of the name speaks for itself.)

Then, in a script:

```
console.log( await import.meta.resolve('#foo/bar.js') );
// It can resolve any type of file, even if you can't import() it.
console.log( await import.meta.resolve('#foo/hello.txt') );
```

As it's a promise-based function, you'll need to await the result.

```
async function example2(path: PathLike){
  return import.meta.resolve(path);
}
```

---

As a side-note: this returns a URL (`file:///...`) so run the result through <del>the built-in URL class</del> [`url.fileURLToPath()`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlfileurltopathurl) if you just want a file path:

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
// OR: const { fileURLToPath } = require('node:url');
// For older node versions use `require('url')`

console.log( fileURLToPath(await import.meta.resolve('#foo/hello.txt')) );
// => /tmp/example/directory-with-modules-in-it/hello.txt
```

Comment: does it ok to just remove `file:///` in windows and linux?

Comment: `fileURLToPath()` (answer updated with an example) handles edge-cases that simply stripping `file:///` doesn't. On Windows especially it's probably not safe to just naively strip the protocol. And the function name 'fileURLToPath' describes what's happening a lot more clear than `url.substr(7)` (plus, you'd need to strip 8 characters on Windows!).

Comment: this is the ultimate complete answer, thanks to you I made this function `export function resolveImports(path: PathLike): Promise<string> {
  return import.meta!.resolve!(path.toString()).then((resolvedPath) =>
    fileURLToPath(resolvedPath)
  );
}`